# angularjs sending request front to back-end

Tags: angularjs, rest

i am sending remove request from front-end using angularjs code for js is

```
       var data = ersutils.getJsonCopy({"id" : $scope.resourceList[idx].id},$scope.resourceList[idx]);
        ResourceService.remove(data, function(data){
            //vm.dtInstance.reloadData(undefined, false);
            $modalInstance.close();
        }, function (resp){
            if(resp.status == 500){
                scope.modalinfo.message = "<code> this resource has booking(s) do you want to delete? </code>"; 
                ResourceService.remove({'id': delRes}, function(){
                    //vm.dtInstance.reloadData(undefined, false);
                    $modalInstance.close();
                })
            }else{
                scope.modalinfo.message = "<code> Unable to delete this Resource </code>";  
            }
        });
```

here ersutils provide jsoncopy for multiple parameters...when i have sent this data to rest api it says that unsupported media type
 restapi code for delete is

```
@DELETE
@Path("/{id:\\d+}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response removeRes(@PathParam("id") int id,Map<String, Object> source){  
    Map<String, Object> resp = new HashMap<>();
    //Map<String, Object> source=new HashMap<>();
    try{              
        resp.put("response",service.removeRes(id,source));
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(resp).build();
    }catch(FrontErsException e){
        resp.put("cause", e.getMessages());
        return Response.status(Status.CONFLICT).entity(resp).build();
    }catch(ErsException e){
        resp.put("cause", e.getMessages());
        return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(resp).build();
    }
}
```

error is 
**angular.js:10514 DELETE http://localhost:8080/ers_dev/rest/resources/10?dynamicFields=%7B%22code%22…2016-05-27%22%7D&firstName=vinay&isHuman=true&name=N%2FA&typeName=Employee 415 (Unsupported Media Type)**

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)` instead of `APPLICATION_JSON`?

Don't know exactly what you're using for your backend, but uUsually DELETE requests doesn't care about request body, so params are URL encoded.

Comment: Some servers consider that using DELETE request with JSON media type is breaking the HTTP Compliance, it could explain the error you received.
Why do you need APPLICATION_JSON for @Consumes ?